# How to correctly configure app.yaml for a standard html page with JS and NodeJS server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I'm setting up a simple web app on AppEngine and have some trouble with configuring the app.yaml. It includes a HTML page, a JS script and a NodeJS server.

**My project structure:**

```
\app.yaml
\package.json
\www
    \index.html
    \js
        \server.js
        \index.js
```

**index.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="JShere" >Hello World !</div>
    <div id="ReqAnswer"></div>
</body>
<script src="js/index"></script>
</html>
```

**index.js:**

```
  document.getElementById('JShere').innerHTML = "JS is running";
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', "/srv", true);
  xhr.send();
  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);

  function processRequest(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('ReqAnswer').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
}
```

**node.js server:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/srv', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Request anwser')
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

**package.json:**

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node www/js/server.js",
    "test": "mocha --exit test/*.test.js"
  },
...
```

**app.yaml:**

```
runtime: nodejs10

handlers:

- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /index
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /page2
  static_files: www/page2.html
  upload: www/page2.html

- url: /www
  static_dir: www
```

When I check locally, *index.js* modify *index.html* correctly but when I deploy it to App Engine, *index.js* is blocked (MIME type (« text/html »)). it then "fails to load the " on the *index.html*. Although, the script still launch the GET request to the server and get a 404 error. 
Is it an App.yaml problem or something else is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check closely the GAE log entries for the exact URL being requested (and rejected with 404). That's what would normally need to be matched by one of your static handlers' `url` pattern. If a match occurs then the file specified by the respective handler's `static_file`/`static_dir` and `upload` specs (which are relative to your app's top dir - where the app.yaml file exists) should happen.

Let's assume the initial request is for `/`. That's matched by your 1st static handler, so your `www/index.html` will be served.

But the `index.html` file references the `js/index` script inside, so another request will follow with that URL. But that URL doesn't match any of your handlers' pattern, so it'll get a 404. You also don't have any file named just `index`.

Assuming what you'd like to serve in this case is actually the `www/js/index.js` file you'd have to:

- correct the filename reference in your `index.html` file:

  `<script src="js/index.js"></script>`
- make sure this reference is matched by a static handler `url` pattern. Something like this maybe (which for every request path ending with `.js` will attempt to serve a file matching that path but relative to the `www/js` directory):

  ```
  - url: /(.*\.js)$
    static_files: www/js/\1
    upload: www/js/.*\.js$
  ```

Alternatively you could use a scheme that can be applied to multiple type of files, not that those ending in `.js`:

- reference the file using the `www` prefix in your `index.html` file:

  ```
  `<script src="www/js/index.js"></script>`
  ```
- re-use your last handler, but adding a wildcard to its `url` to ensure matches for everything under `www` (as `www/blah` won't match the just `www` pattern):

  ```
  `- url: /www/*`
  ```

It's also possible to reference the script without the `.js` suffix, but then you'd need a handler specifically for that file - to map it to the actual filename, you can't use wildcards. So I wouldn't recommend this as it can get pretty complex very quickly.

You'd have to similarly consider all the other static elements you need to serve.

Comment: I just fixed it myselft using a specific handler, but as you said, it wil get ugly in no time. Thanks for the great and complete explanation/sugestions ! I'm gonna work on that !